# Rails + Sidekiq not recognizing class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I have a `CsvImport` service object in my `app/services` and I'm trying to call one of the class methods from within a Worker.

```
class InventoryUploadWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(file_path, company_id)
    CsvImport.csv_import(file_path, Company.find(company_id))
  end
end
```

But it seems that the worker doesn't know what the class is, I've attempted `require 'csv_import'` to no avail.

Heres where it breaks:

`WARN: ArgumentError: undefined class/module CsvImport`

The method being called in
csv_import.rb

```
class CsvImport
require "benchmark"
require 'csv'


def self.csv_import(filename, company)
    time = Benchmark.measure do
        File.open(filename) do |file|
            headers = file.first
            file.lazy.each_slice(150) do |lines|
                Part.transaction do 
                    inventory = []
                    insert_to_parts_db = []
                    rows = CSV.parse(lines.join, write_headers: true, headers: headers)
                    rows.map do |row|
                        part_match = Part.find_by(part_num: row['part_num'])
                        new_part = build_new_part(row['part_num'], row['description']) unless part_match
                        quantity = row['quantity'].to_i
                        row.delete('quantity')
                        row["condition"] = match_condition(row)
                        quantity.times do 
                            part = InventoryPart.new(
                                part_num: row["part_num"], 
                                description: row["description"], 
                                condition: row["condition"],
                                serial_num: row["serial_num"],
                                company_id: company.id,
                                part_id: part_match ? part_match.id : new_part.id
                                )           
                            inventory << part                   
                        end
                    end
                    InventoryPart.import inventory
                end
            end
        end         
    end
    puts time
end
```

Comment: Can you post that file, `CsvImport`?

Comment: I posted the class/method being called for brevity. @Iceman

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: 4.2.5.1 @Iceman

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you manage to fix it? I have created another stackoverflow post with this problem, but it´s pretty amazing that noone answers something that looks basic.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61329524/sidekiq-calling-methods-in-library-files?noredirect=1#comment108497423_61329524

Answer (score 1):

your requires are inside the class. Put them outside the class so they're required right away when the file is loaded, not when the class is loaded.

Instead of

```
class CsvImport
require "benchmark"
require 'csv'
...
```

Do this

```
require "benchmark"
require 'csv'
class CsvImport
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add to `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services"]
```

More details here: [autoload-paths](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths)

Comment: Autoload paths automatically pick any custom directories under app. For example, if your application has app/presenters, or app/services, etc., they are added to autoload paths.