# Sidekiq calling methods in library files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I´m new to sidekiq. I tested a very basic example and it´s working fine. Now, inside my job, I would like to call a method that is in a library in my lib folder but I´m getting some errors related to paths.

First, I define the files and structure:

1. I have created a worker in my-project/app/workers/hard-worker.rb

`require 'sidekiq'`

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = {db:1}
end 

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = {db:1}
end 


class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform()
    puts "Initializing availabilities integration..."
    CustomService.getAvailabilities
  end
end
```

This method `CustomService.getAvailabilities` is in `my-project/lib/custom_service.rb`

This custom_service.rb requires some other files:

```
require 'photo_service'
require 'open-uri'
require 'RMagick'
require 'boat_utils_service'


class MMKService  

def self.getAvailabilities()
 do whatever
end
end
```

The point it that this library is called and currently working by the user interface in our web app GUI, so, should be used from both GUI and background jobs.

I´m running the worker like: `bundle exec sidekiq -r ./hard_worker.rb`

The problem is when I run the worker job:
1. I get error until I require library like: require '../../lib/custom_service.rb'
2. I get error in custom_service.rb file with the require libraries. `require': cannot load such file -- photo_service (LoadError)

What am I missing? Do I need to update all my require paths?

Comment: Does it work when you call form the rails console : `HardWorker.perform_async` ?

Comment: No. From the rails console is where I get the errors related with paths. It´s working from the website GUI.